# Animate using CSS3

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/MhJ2Y/).According to this fiddle when the `class='hide'` is added into any span,it should be animate,however it is not working well.I want to animate the span when a `class='hide'` is added.It should animate while changing the width.

Comment: please post the code here

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are defining `width: auto` as one of the frames of the animation. CSS animations mostly only work with fixed values.

Try setting `width: 100px` for example and check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/MhJ2Y/3/

A solution to this could be getting & setting the width to a fixed value via jQuery on document load.